# What is wrong in my example with this lambda function in C++ - compilation error?

Tags: c++, lambda

I am new to lambda and functors. I was trying to exercise the lambda function.

I am trying to use the lambda function as the following. However, I get a compilation error on the following line .

```
auto lambda = [] ( DemoAssignOpera& val)->void
        {
if (val.getPrivVar1() > 10 )
{

    std::cout<<"The obj has priv1 greater than 10";
}
    };
```

What is the wrong with the above expression?

Here is the compilation error -

```
01:06:48 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Algorithms_STL ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
../main.cpp:153:2: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        auto lambda = [] ( DemoAssignOpera& val)->void
        ^
../main.cpp:153:16: error: expected expression
        auto lambda = [] ( DemoAssignOpera& val)->void
                      ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1

01:06:48 Build Finished (took 417ms)
```

I am trying to use this expression in conjunction with the following code.

```
for_each(listElements.begin(),listElements.end(),lambda);
```

My class is

```
class DemoAssignOpera
{

private:

    int priv_var1;
    int priv_var2;

public:

    void setDemoAssignOpera(int b1, int b2)
    {
        std::cout<<"Set the values"<<std::endl;
        priv_var1 = b1;
        priv_var2 = b2;

    }

    int getPrivVar1()
    {
        return priv_var1;
    }

    void showDemoAssignOpera()
    {
        std::cout<<"The priv_var1 = "<<priv_var1<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"The priv_var2 = "<<priv_var2<<std::endl;
    }

    DemoAssignOpera operator=(const DemoAssignOpera & oldObj)
    {
        std::cout<<"The user-defined assignment operator is invoked"<<std::endl;
        priv_var1 = oldObj.priv_var1;
        std::cout<<"Tweaking the assignment Operator"<<std::endl;
        priv_var2 =  300;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator<(const DemoAssignOpera & otherbj) const
    {
        bool ret = false;

        if(otherbj.priv_var1 > priv_var1 )
        {
            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }

/** This will be used by find() algorithm to match the priv_var1 **/
   bool operator==(const DemoAssignOpera & oldObj) const
   {
     bool ret = false;

     if(priv_var1 == oldObj.priv_var1 )
     {
        ret = true;
     }

    return ret;
  }

};
```

Comment: In the interest of making this question findable for other people encountering the same compile error, please indicate *what* the error was (preferably with a verbatim copy-and-paste of the error-message). Without that, this question is not very useful, and is liable to be closed.

Comment: Your code [compiles without an error on ideone](http://ideone.com/rhHC4K).

Comment: Could be you are missing a flag to switch to the c++11 standard? something like this _-std=c++11_ on the command line

Comment: updated compilation error now. I am using eclipse on my mac-book to compile a C++ program.

Comment: @user2587326: OP has now updated his/her question, and the added content shows that you are correct. Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: Thanks ruakh. Hoping it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a feature that is not present in the C++ standard that is selected as a default in Eclipse that you use. Please switch to the C++11 version of C++ standard to compile your code. As dasblinkenlight mentioned, it can compile fine, you just need to set the correct version of C++ standard.

For Eclipse, please check the Eclipse FAQ, which explains how to do that:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features

You probably want to use -std=c++11 instead of -std=c++0x as it is now official, but both should work.

Answer (score 0):

A functor object is an object that overload the () operator. Using a function object in your code will look like this:

```
for_each(listElements.begin(),listElements.end(), CheckPrivVar);
```

while `CheckPrivVar` will be:

```
struct CheckPrivVar
{
 void operator() (const DemoAssignOpera& val)
 {
   if (val.getPrivVar1() > 10 )
      std::cout<<"The obj has priv1 greater than 10";
 }
};
```

if you want to use a lambda try this:

```
for_each(listElements.begin(),listElements.end(), [] (const DemoAssignOpera& val)
         {  if (val.getPrivVar1() > 10 )
              std::cout<<"The obj has priv1 greater than 10";
         };
```